# Run "as" normal user vs. Run "with" normal user

Tags: terminology, programming, non-native-english

On [Linux Mint 19](https://linuxmint.com/download.php), I have a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) with a command which should output a sentence:

> Target 'distrib' has to be run **as** normal user!

in case the user has run it as / with the [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) user.

---

Since I am not a native English speaker, I now hesitate if it would be better phrase it like this:

> Target 'distrib' has to be run **with** normal user!

Clarification will be much appreciated!

---

<sub>I will only add, that I am here for the first time, so please, if I have written anything not under your guidelines, feel free to comment or edit my question directly.</sub>

---

Research:

At least on Windows it is common to use ***Run as***.

Note:

I am interested in US English wording if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, *with normal user* doesn't work; *with normal user privileges* does.

But if the people reading this error message have extensive experience with computers, they should understand *as*; that preposition is used in this context frequently (and not just on Windows). If they don't, I suspect that even *with normal user privileges* is too short for them to figure out what is going on.